# First column as link in SharePoint view

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a custom list with below two columns.

```
Col 1
Col 2
```

In the default view, "Title" column is the link to view item. I have removed this column from this view but I am not able to set Col 1 as my link to view item. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create the list definition and view in visual studio then you can set it in the  section of the view:

```
<ViewFields> 
 <FieldRef Name="Col1" LinkToItem="TRUE"/> 
 <FieldRef Name="Col2"/> 
</ViewFields>
```

If you're using the UI then you need to modify the view using SharePoint designer, when you get the view shown in SPD select a cell in col1 and click the > arrow
[image]
Then set a checkmark in "Show link to Item"
[image]
Save

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the title column you can rename the title column with the required column name.means rename Title column with Col1,listsettings-->Click on title column -->change name to col1 and save